# Issue with integer column return with alphanumeric value

Tags: mysql

I have a query where there are 2 conditions used one for id and another for project_id , id is type int(10) and project_id is type varchar(250) and I having issue with this query please see the image. According to normal login it should only return the row with id 57 but its returning 2 rows which wrong. Can anyone please help me out  [image]

Comment: what's the point in using id='project' id condition?

Comment: The result is correct when testing a string against an integer mysql will convert the leading numeric characters hence id 7 is returned when tested against '7q...'

Comment: so how can I solve it , I mean shouldn't return the row with id 7.

Comment: I'm afraid it's up to you to understand how mysql works - please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
select * from `projects` where `id` = 57 and `project_id` = '7QJYouUh'
```

You have input wrong id And you want to log in so, you to set condition 'and'.